# Why does PHP believe my date is a string?

Tags: php, date

My code is giving me the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function sub() on string" As you can see the $date variable is a string based on the echo, but it still believes it to be a string.

**My code:**

```
echo $stringDate;
    //PRINTS "2014-03-27"
$date = date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime( $stringDate );
echo $date;
    //PRINTS "14141414-0303-2727"
$date->sub(new date_interval_create_from_date_string('70 days') );
    //Produces "Fatal error: Call to a member function sub() on string"
$milestones["Method Development Checklist"]['date'] = $date;
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date `date()` returns a string... so...  duh?

Comment: [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) methods work on DateTime __objects__, not on strings.... `$date = new DateTime($stringDate);`

Comment: And `'yyyy-mm-dd'` is a weird format for a date in PHP.... perhaps you're confusing PHP with MS Excel format masks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
date('yyyy-mm-dd', strtotime( $stringDate ));
```

use

```
date_create_from_format("Y-m-d", $stringDate);
```

which is an alias for

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $stringDate);
```

Have a nice day o/

Comment: Hmm, it's now returning "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" which unfortunately doesn't include why.